# C++: Compile Error for Template Assignment Operator Overloading

Tags: c++

I keep getting the error "use of class template requires template argument list" when I compile the following code in VC++6. What is wrong with it?

```
template <class T>  
class StdVector{  
    public:                 
        StdVector & operator=(const StdVector &v);
};

template <typename T>  
StdVector & StdVector<T>::operator=(const StdVector &v){  
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the template parameter in the return type:

```
template <typename T>  
StdVector<T> & StdVector<T>::operator=(const StdVector &v)
{  
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: No, because by the time the compiler has reached the parameter list, it's effectively in the scope of the class and the template name is now equivalent to the full template id. But checking now you've sown the seeds of doubt!

Comment: Ha, I've always wrote them, here's the chance to learn my new thing for the day. :P

Comment: @GMan: No, `<T>` in the parameter declaration is optional.

Comment: Hm, good to know. Would you guys include it explicitly or not? Which do you find more readable?

Comment: Personally, I go without. It's not like there's usually a shortage of verbose template parameters in most C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
template <typename T>  
StdVector<T> & StdVector<T>::operator=(const StdVector<T> &v)
{  
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to add `<T>` to the parameter declaration